# Weak convergence related to Hermite polynomial?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions, quantum-mechanics

I am reading Griffiths's quantum mechanics book; in the section about harmonic oscillators, he wrote out the amplitude of wave function, and compared with the classical harmonic oscillators. He presented the following picture on page 53:

[image]

The picture seems to suggeste that when $n\to\infty$, the quantum amplitudes, after some renomalization, converge weakly to the classical one. Translate into mathematics, we ask

Question: Can we prove that the functions
$$
f_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^nn!}\sqrt{\frac{2n+1}{\pi}}
H_n^2(\sqrt{2n+1}x)e^{-(2n+1)x^2}
$$
converge weakly to $\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ on $[-1, 1]$ (and $0$ outside $[-1, 1]$)? Here $H_n(x)=(-1)^ne^{x^2}(e^{-x^2})^{(n)}$ is physicists' Hermite polynomial.

Comment: Do you have a response to the answers below?

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: Thanks for all the answers! I see this should follow from the formula on Szego's book. Did Szego actually prove this formula in his book? He cited a 1929 paper of Plancherel and Rotach, which I found difficult to follow at certain spots.

Comment: Yes, there is a rather involved proof of formula (8.22.12) in the book. Actually, the proof is provided, on pp. 227--230 of the book, for the (in a sense) more general Laguerre polynomials. At the end of that proof, on p. 230, it is mentioned that formula (8.22.12) then immediately follows by virtue of the expressions (5.6.1) on p. 106 of the book of the Hermite polynomials in terms of Laguerre polynomials for $\alpha=\pm1/2$.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: Thank you for the help! I think the $O(1/n)$ term is valid only when $x$ stays bounded (here $x$ is as in Szego's 8.22.12). If we only know $x<(1-\epsilon_0)\sqrt{2n+1}$, then we can use the more primitive version of the asymptotic formula (the stuff inside $\sin$ or $\cos$ is not linear in $x$) to argue.

Comment: (i) Why do you think "the $O(1/n)$ term is valid only when $x$ stays bounded"? Did you find a mistake in Szego's proof? (ii) What do you mean by "we only know $x<(1−\epsilon_0)\sqrt{2n+1}$"? (iii) What do you mean by  "the more primitive version of the asymptotic formula"? (iv) Have you found any mistakes or missing details in my proof?

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis Actually I read the Plancherel-Rotach paper and did not read Szego's proof (not sure how much I must read). At some stage, one does Taylor series with variable $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2n+2}}$, and declare $O(1/n)$, etc. whenever $n$ has power one on the denominator; but that is not small if $x\sim \sqrt n$, like $x=(1-\epsilon_0)\sqrt{2n+2}$ - so cannot really say $O(1/n)$. For (ii), that is equivalent to Szego's condition $\epsilon<\phi<\pi-\epsilon$ in 8.22.9(a).  For (iii). Plancherel-Rotach used Cauchy integral formula, initially ends with sine of a nonlinear expression.

Comment: Again, have you found any mistakes or missing details in my proof?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following asymptotics of Hermite polynomials can be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials):
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^{-x^2/2}H_n(x)&=&\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{n/2}\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\left(x\sqrt{2n}-\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)+O(n^{-1})\right)\\
&\times&\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2n+1}\right)^{-1/4},\quad n\to\infty.
\end{eqnarray*}
By scaling the independent variable, squaring and using $\cos^2(nx)\to 1/2$ weakly, you obtain your statement.

Remark. This is also true for other one-dimensional Schrodinger operators, and is proved by the so-called JWKB method. See, for example

A. Eremenko and A. Gabrielov, High energy eigenfunctions of one-dimensional Schrödinger operators with polynomial coefficients, Computational Methods and Function Theory, 8 (2008). No. 2, 513--529.

Remark. Since doubts about Wikipedia formula are expressed in the comments, I confirm it with the "primary source":

G. Szego, Orthogonal polynomials, AMS, 1939,
Theorem 8.22.9 (a), formula (8.22.12).

Comment: What is the meaning of the relation $\sim$ here? Under what conditions on $x$ does it hold and why? It clearly cannot be the usual: $a\sim b$ meaning that $a=(1+o(1))b$. And why can you rescale the way you do, by the infinitely large factor $\sqrt{2n+1}$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis From what you write, I take it that it's not the usual asymptotic relation because the zeroes don't match up. I haven't time to check this closely, but the expression is from the Wikipedia page, which cites Abramowitz and Stegun 13.5.16 and 13.6.38 on pages 508 and 510, which can be seen here: https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cbm/aands/frameindex.htm. Hope that helps.

Comment: @user196574 : The information in Abramowitz and Stegun is different from that in Wikipedia. This is one of the cases when what Wikipedia says should not be taken at the face value.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: I corrected a misprint which I made while copying from Wikipedia, spelled explicitly the error term, and added a reliable source.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : Formula (8.22.12) in Theorem 8.22.9 (a) of G. Szego, Orthogonal polynomials, AMS, 1939 is very different from the one in your answer. It looks like what you actually have now done is mostly keep the same Wikipedia formula, just inserting $O(n^{-1})$ in it, without explaining the meaning of $O(n^{-1})$ (that is, for what $x$ it holds).

Comment: Previous comment continued: I strongly suspect that, with that apparently non-existing formula, you will actually never be able to "By scaling the independent variable, squaring and using $\cos^2(nx)\to 1/2$ weakly, [...] obtain [the required] statement". If I am mistaken about this, please provide a detailed proof of the just quoted claim of yours.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Also, about "a misprint which I made while copying from Wikipedia"; Actually, you had copied the Wikipedia formula faithfully. The problem is it is hardly possible to attach a meaning to that formula.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: Misprint was in another place: I omitted the minus sign in front of the exponent 1/4.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : I guess you clarified it about the "misprint". What about all the other issues raised in my comments?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}$Your conjecture is true.

Indeed, let $h_n(u):=H_n(u)e^{-u^2/2}$ and $c_n:=\dfrac1{2^n n!}\sqrt{\dfrac{2n+1}\pi}$, so that $f_n(x)=c_nh_n(x\sqrt{2n+1})^2$.
Take any $\ep\in(0,1)$. Then, by formula (8.22.12) in Theorem 8.22.9 (a) of G. Szego, Orthogonal polynomials, AMS, 1939, for natural $n$ and any $X\in[0,1-\ep]$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    F_n(X)&:=\int_0^X dx\,f_n(x)^2  \\ 
    &=\int_{\arccos X}^{\pi/2} dt\,\sin t\,c_nh_n(\sqrt{2n+1}\,\cos t)^2    \\ 
    &=\frac1\pi\sqrt{\frac{4n+2}n}
    \int_{\arccos X}^{\pi/2} dt\,\Big[\sin^2\Big(\frac{3\pi}4-\frac{2n+1}4\,a(t)\Big)+O(1/n)\Big]   \\ 
    &=\frac{2+o(1)}\pi\,I_n(X)+O(1/n), 
\end{aligned}   
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
(as $n\to\infty$) uniformly in such $X$, where $a(t):=2t-\sin2t$ and
\begin{equation*}
    I_n(X):=\int_{\arccos X}^{\pi/2} dt\,\sin^2\Big(\frac{3\pi}4-\frac{2n+1}4\,a(t)\Big); 
\end{equation*}
the mentioned formula from Szego was used in line 3 of \eqref{1}.

Note that $a'(t)=2(1-\cos2t)\ge2(1-\cos2\arccos X)>0$ for $t\in[\arccos X,\pi/2]$, since $X\in[0,1-\ep]$. So, the function $a\colon[\arccos X,\pi/2]\mapsto[a(\arccos X),a(\pi/2)]$ has an inverse $a^{-1}$ with the bounded derivative $\dfrac1{a'\circ a^{-1}}$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    I_n(X)=\int_{a(\arccos X)}^{a(\pi/2)} 
    \dfrac{ds}{a'(a^{-1}(s))}\,\sin^2\Big(\frac{3\pi}4-\frac{2n+1}4\,s\Big). 
\end{equation*}
Since $\sin^2 z=\frac12\,(1-\cos2z)$, by the Riemann--Lebesgue lemma we have
\begin{equation*}
    I_n(X)\to\frac12\,\int_{a(\arccos X)}^{a(\pi/2)} 
    \dfrac{ds}{a'(a^{-1}(s))}
    =\frac12\,\int_{\arccos X}^{\pi/2} dt=\frac{\pi/2-\arccos X}2.  
\end{equation*}
So, by \eqref{1}, for each $X\in[0,1)$
\begin{equation*}
    F_n(X)\to F(X),  
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    F(X):=\left\{
    \begin{aligned}
    \frac12-\frac1\pi\arccos X &\text{ if }X\in[0,1], \\ 
    \frac12&\text{ if }X\ge1. 
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{equation*}
Note also that (i) the function $F$ is continuous, (ii) $F_n(\infty):=\int_0^\infty dx\,f_n(x)^2=\frac12$, (iii) the functions $f_n$ are even, and (iv) $F'(X)=\dfrac1{\pi\sqrt{1-X^2}}$ for $X\in[0,1)$.

Now the desired conclusion immediately follows, since the weak convergence of a sequence of probability measures on $\mathbb R$ is equivalent to the convergence of the corresponding c.d.f.'s to the limit c.d.f. at all points of continuity of the limit c.d.f. $\quad\Box$

---

The just obtained result can probably be extracted from the apparently much more [general result](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Weak-convergence-of-orthogonal-polynomials-Assche/9c546e7f9b11d39395d2420cce27e8c633b8cef8). However, the above, more direct proof seemed easier for me to get.